# HTML/Javascript Form Isn't Returning Answer

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am very new to JavaScript and HTML webpages. I currently have a regression model that predicts the prices of houses in my town. How can I use JavaScript to have the user input information about their house, and the website output a predicted price value?

I want the user to be able to input many values. Some of which include the lot size, year built, square feet of the home, and whether the home is a single-family or a townhome. For simplicity, let's say my model is price = 100,000 + 50,000lot + 2,000built + 4000SqFt + 0Townhome

I tried filling out the form, but when I clicked the "Predict My Home's Value" button at the end, the answer did not appear. Rather, the entire form just became blank and that's it. What I want is the actual home's price to appear.

Here is my actual code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h1>Home Prices Calculator</h1>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  function getPrice() {
    var form = document.getElementById("calc");
    var out = form.elements["z"];
    //get numbers
    var sqftVal = parseInt(form.elements["sqft"].value);
    var bathsVal = parseInt(form.elements["baths"].value);
    var builtVal = parseInt(form.elements["built"].value);
    var lotVal = parseInt(form.elements["lot"].value);
    
    for (i=0;i<document.forms[0].zipcode.length;i++) {
        if (document.forms[0].zipcode[i].checked) {
            var zipVal = document.forms[0].radios[i].value;
        }
    }
    
    for (i=0;i<document.forms[0].zipcode.length;i++) {
        if (document.forms[0].gar[i].checked) {
            var garageVal = document.forms[0].gar[i].value;
        }
    }
    
    for (i=0;i<document.forms[0].zipcode.length;i++) {
        if (document.forms[0].housetype[i].checked) {
            var houseVal = document.forms[0].housetype[i].value;
        }
    }
    
    out.value = -6932000 + 221400 * Math.log(sqftVal) + 637.2 * Math.exp(bathsVal) + 2868 * builtVal + 159100 * lotVal
    
  }
  
</script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <form id = "calc" oninput="updateOutput()">
    
    <fieldset>
      <legend>ZIP Code</legend>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="47" name="zipcode" value="47">
        <label for="47">12345</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="47" name="zipcode" value="47">
        <label for="47">12346</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <legend>House Type</legend>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="sf" name="housetype" value="sf">
        <label for="sf">Single Family</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="tw" name="housetype" value="tw">
        <label for="tw">Townhouse/Condo</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Square Feet</legend>
      <input name = "sqft" id="sqft" type = "number" min = "0" max = "8000">
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Number of Bathrooms</legend>
      <input name = "baths" id="baths" type = "number" step = "0.5" min = "0.5" max = "6.5">
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Year Built</legend>
      <input name = "built" id="built" type = "number" min = "1988" max = "2020">
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Lot Size (in Acres)</legend>
      <input name = "lot" id = "lot" type = "number" step = "0.01" min = "0" max = "1.54">
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Number of Garages</legend>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="a" name="gar" value="a">
        <label for="a">0</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="b" name="gar" value="b">
        <label for="b">1</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="c" name="gar" value="c">
        <label for="c">2</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="d" name="gar" value="d">
        <label for="d">3</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    
    <button onclick="getPrice()">Predict My Home's Value</button>
    
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to thank you in advance to those who will help me with this. I appreciate that your time is important and that this is a VERY basic question for many of you. I'm sure it is something small that I am just missing. I am very new to this.

Here is what part of the webpage looks like (it is in it's very early stages).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, the default value for the button `type` attribute is `submit`, clicking it will submit the form, which will refresh the page, it may seem instantaneous if there's not much to load but that's why/how it resets.

There are at least 2 options to fix it:

**Option 1**:

Set the button type to `button`

```html
<button type="button" onclick="getPrice()">Predict My Home's Value</button>
```

**Option 2**:

1. pass the event object to the onclick like so

```html
<button onclick="getPrice(event)">Predict My Home's Value</button>
```

2. prevent the page refresh with `event.preventDefault()`

```js
function getPrice(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful @lonut Achim , but when I do this, the page doesn't refresh, and the value doesn't appear. How can I get the home price number to appear on the screen?

Comment: Does you app crash? It should if there isn't  a form element with `name="z"` in there

Comment: that could be the problem. It does not crash. Am I not getting the information from the form to the function properly?

Comment: You sure? Have you checked the console? Is that element present, because I don't see it?

Comment: I am using GitHub, so I have no console

Comment: I don't know what to do to fix that. Not exactly sure what you mean

Comment: Well, if that is all your code, there are 2 issues:

1. your first for loop checks for `document.forms[0].zipcode[i].checked` but uses the value from `document.forms[0].radios[i].value` - notice `zipcode` changed to `radios`

2. There's no form element with `name="z"` to add the value to

Comment: Yes, I realize that, but how do I add the form element?

Comment: Just add it anywhere inside the form, just like you would with any other input, maybe right above the button? Your choice. E.g.: `<input name="z" />`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218322/discussion-between-ionut-achim-and-324).